# Using dplyr in order to change values under threshold in specific colums

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe such as :

```
dt <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                 Col2 = c(0.04, 0.03, 0.003, 0.43, 0.47, 0.0009),
                 Col3 = c(34, 23, 23, 34, 1, 2))
```

```
  Col1   Col2 Col3
1    A 0.0400   34
2    B 0.0300   23
3    C 0.0030   23
4    D 0.4300   34
5    E 0.4700    1
6    F 0.0009    2
```

And I would like to use dplyr in ordrer to :

1. Replace in Col2 every value < 0.05 by X & every value => 0.05 by Z
   2  Replace in Col3 every value < 5 by Y & every value => 5 by W

I should get :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A X W
B X W
C X W 
D Z W
E Z Y
F X Y
```

Comment: can you please check my solution

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
dt %>% mutate(Col2 = case_when(Col2 < 0.05 ~ "X",
                               Col2 >= 0.05 ~ "Z"),
              Col3 = case_when(Col3 < 5 ~ "W",
                              Col3 >=5 ~ "Y"))
```

Comment: Ok  @broti thank you very much! What is the syntax if I want to transform a value comprised between [0.05 and 0.09] for instance ?

Comment: You would just do `Col2 >= 0.05 & Col2 <= 0.09`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` in `base R`

```
dt[2:3] <-  Map(function(x, y, z) ifelse(x > y, z[2],
        z[1]), dt[2:3], c(0.05, 5), list(c('X', 'Z'), c('Y', 'W')))

dt
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    A    X    W
#2    B    X    W
#3    C    X    W
#4    D    Z    W
#5    E    Z    Y
#6    F    X    Y
```